# Control pressed state of Android Up button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-drawable

I'm trying to control what color the pressed state of the android up/back icon + title text in the action bar will be.

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up_button</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/H4.Other</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/h4_other</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/kf_white</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/H5.Blue</item>
</style>
```

As you can see I've defined by own up indicator. I've tried making that a selector but that only deals with the icon I provided, not the combined icon + title text for which Android provides a standard pressed color. The reason I'm asking this is because on some Samsung devices, the standard pressed color is a weird blue which doesn't fit with the style of my app.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selector</item>
```

in your AppTheme. selector.xml will be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:constantSize="false"
android:enterFadeDuration="0"
 android:exitFadeDuration="0" >
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/color1" />
<item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```